# SQLite Room request, get value if found, or MAX(value)+1 if not

Tags: sqlite, max, android-sqlite, coalesce

Suppose I have the following table:

| value | label |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | art2 |
| 2 | art1 |
| 3 | art4 |
| 4 | art3 |

I would like to have the result:

- value field if label found
- MAX(value)+1 if not found

```
label = art4 => 3
label = non existing => MAX(value)+1 = 5
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT COALESCE(
         MAX(CASE WHEN label = ? THEN value END), 
         MAX(VALUE) + 1,
         1
       ) AS value
FROM tablename;
```

This query will also return `1` if the table is empty.
Change `?` to the label that you want.

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/IPa4bI9R).

Answer (score 1):

I believe that the following would do what you wish:-

```
SELECT coalesce((SELECT value FROM example WHERE label = 'artx'),(SELECT max(value) FROM example) + 1) AS value;
```

- where **example** is the table name and **artx** is the label (in this case a label that will not be found)
- This uses the **coalesce** function which returns the first non null value. So in the case of the first subquery returning a value because the label was found, then the value associated with that label. In the case when the label is not found then null will be returned and then the second subquery will return the highest value + 1.

As an example/demo consider the following which produces a result for all scenarios :-

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS example; /* JUST IN CASE THE ENVIRONMENT IS NOT CLEAN */
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS example (value INTEGER,label TEXT); /* Create the example table */
INSERT INTO example VALUES (1,'art2'),(2,'art1'),(3,'art4'),(4,'art3'); /* load the data into the example table */
/* To test run all possible scenarios, combining the results as one set of rows (UNION) */
SELECT coalesce((SELECT value FROM example WHERE label = 'artx'),(SELECT max(value) FROM example) + 1) AS value
UNION ALL
SELECT coalesce((SELECT value FROM example WHERE label = 'art1'),(SELECT max(value) FROM example) + 1) AS value
UNION ALL
SELECT coalesce((SELECT value FROM example WHERE label = 'art2'),(SELECT max(value) FROM example) + 1) AS value
UNION ALL
SELECT coalesce((SELECT value FROM example WHERE label = 'art3'),(SELECT max(value) FROM example) + 1) AS value
UNION ALL
SELECT coalesce((SELECT value FROM example WHERE label = 'art4'),(SELECT max(value) FROM example) + 1) AS value
;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS example; /* CLEANUP TESTING ENVIRONMENT */
```

This results in :-

[image]

- 1st row artx label not found so highest value (4) + 1 = 5
- 2nd row art1 label found so value 2 returned
- 3rd row art2 label found so value 1 returned
- 4th row art3 label found so value 4 returned
- 5th row art4 label found so value 3 returned